# Identical UPDATE SQL on identical recordset seems to be misbehaving with MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

**Issue**: Logic seems misbehaving with MariaDB.

**Objective**: Create a self referencing ID column value to refer to the immediate previous record.

**Description**: We have a very large table of records with ID as Primary key and time of the record, distributed among Terminals. We want to create a column to hold the ID value of the immediate previous record of the current record for the same Terminal depending on the time of the record which we will use to make self join to select the previous record of the current record side by side in the same recordset, in order to boost the query performance, than selecting previous records on the fly during each query.

**Expectation**: Understanding of what is actually happenning and a cross database engine (at least MySQL & MariaDB) compatible UPDATE query with optimum performance.

```
UPDATE tst_terminaldata SET PreviousID = NULL;

UPDATE tst_terminaldata AS TD
SET TD.PreviousID =
    (SELECT TDP.ID FROM
        (SELECT TDP2.ID, TDP2.Time, TDP2.TerminalID
                         FROM tst_terminaldata AS TDP2
                         ORDER BY 
  TDP2.Time DESC, TDP2.ID DESC /* Works for- Windows: MySQL 8.0.16, 5.7.11; Linux: MySQL 8.0.13, 8.0, 5.7.20 */
  TDP2.Time ASC, TDP2.ID ASC /* Works for- Windows: MariaDB 10.4.7; Linux: MariaDB 10.2.25, 10.1.40 */
        ) AS TDP
        WHERE TDP.TerminalID = TD.TerminalID
          AND TDP.Time < TD.Time
        LIMIT 1
    ) 
WHERE TD.PreviousID IS NULL;

SELECT TD.* FROM tst_terminaldata AS TD
      ORDER BY TD.TerminalID ASC, TD.Time DESC, TD.ID DESC;
```

**Case**: The MySQL SQL seems logical to me, not the MariaDB one. But both works on respective cases (as commented in the SQL), which should not be.

**Sample data**:

```
ID  TerminalID  Time    PreviousID
1   1   2019-07-29 13:56:37 NULL
2   1   2019-07-29 13:56:52 NULL
3   2   2019-07-29 13:57:01 NULL
4   1   2019-07-29 13:57:02 NULL
5   2   2019-07-29 13:57:08 NULL
6   1   2019-07-29 13:57:17 NULL
7   2   2019-07-29 13:57:23 NULL
8   1   2019-07-29 13:57:32 NULL
```

Comment: Just in case if you need the table that holds the data;

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JoF6IPdaaMzS-wUMSijF7g1W6RRdfQ_u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I felt I should clarify that the TerminalID Is not the focal point here. You can delete all the other records than for TerminalID 1 and erase the TerminalID related SQL and will experience the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `ORDER BY` in a Derived table is ignored by both MySQL and MariaDB (at least in the versions you tried).
- The Optimizer is free to present the rows in any order.
- The Optimizer code for MySQL and MariaDB diverged in this area at about 5.6 / 10.0.

This should explain why you *appear* to get different results based on the `ORDER BY` and Version.

If you are inserting 1700 rows per second, I hope you are batching them and using SSDs.

I don't know what the goal of the query is, but I would recommend digesting the data as it arrives, rather than struggling with "lag" type queries.

Comment: You are correct. However, inner ORDER BY clause is respected by MySQL. And more interestingly, MariaDB doesn't actually ignore it, just misbehaves, changing the inner ASC <=> DESC changes the result set for MariaDB in a reverse way. And yes, am using batch INSERT per minute and it is SSD.

Comment: @BrokenArrow - Whether it _seems_ to honor ASC or turn it into DESC _today_ is irrelevant.  _Tomorrow_ it may do something different.  Do _NOT_ depend on inner `ORDER BYs`.  (This has been discussed in more detail in several Q&A here, plus in obscure places first in MariaDB, and later in MySQL.)

Comment: Agreed with that. MySQL seems a better place than MariaDB in terms of solidification.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need [LAG](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/lag/) function here -

```
UPDATE tst_terminaldata AS TD
SET TD.PreviousID = (SELECT TerminalID, LAG(TerminalID) OVER(PARTITION BY TerminalID ORDER BY TIME
                     FROM tst_terminaldata) T
WHERE T.TerminalID = TD.TerminalID
```

Though i have not tried it but i think this should work.

Comment: MySQL: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: @brokenArrow, Try now.

Comment: MariaDB:: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY TerminalID ORDER BY TIME                      FROM tst_terminaldat' at line 2

Comment: You can think aside of TerminalID here. Check my comment on the post.

Comment: Which MaraiDB version you are using.

Comment: In the SQL as comments

Comment: I meant what is the version of your mariaDB DBMS? It might not support analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join` with `lag()`:

```
update tst_terminaldata td join
       (select td2.*, lag(id) over (partition by TerminalID order by time) as prev_id
        from tst_terminaldata td2
       ) td2
       on td.id = td2.id
    set previousid = prev_id;
```

Comment: MySQL: Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'td'

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after some study, I find this is a MariaDB specific issue which they say is not a bug but ultimately simulates a buggy result!

The descending sort order is the correct approach, which works on MySQL but not with MariaDB.

However, after comparing variants, I find, taking out the ORDER BY clause from the inner SELECT to the outer SELECT makes the query both MySQL & MariaDB compliant with a performance degrade.

But amazingly, at least in my case, with 12 records per minute from each tracking device, with ~8500 of such devices, on a CentOS VPS with dual core and 2GB RAM, it looked like the point of the process to update each record with immediate previous record's primary key value as a reference doesn't make any difference versus dynamic JOIN, rather sometimes the dynamic JOIN beats the straight JOIN by ~15% of performance!

**Straight JOIN**:

```
SELECT * FROM tst_terminaldata AS TD
LEFT JOIN tst_terminaldata AS TDP ON TDP.ID = TD.PreviousID
```

**Dynamic JOIN**:

```
SELECT * FROM tst_terminaldata AS TD
LEFT JOIN tst_terminaldata AS TDP ON TDP.ID = (
    SELECT TDP2.ID FROM tst_terminaldata AS TDP2 
    WHERE TDP2.Time > TD.Time AND TDP2.TerminalID = TD.TerminalID 
    ORDER BY TDP2.Time DESC, TDP2.ID DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```